# OpenTok (iOS) v2.4.0 (64-bit) -- Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, xcode6, armv7, arm64, opentok

I'm trying to upgrade to the latest version of OpenTok iOS SDK. However, I keep getting the tons of linking errors like the ones below. It seems as if this latest version does not support armv7.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(short)", referenced from:
webrtc::NetEqImpl::DecodeLoop(std::__1::list<webrtc::Packet*, std::__1::allocator<webrtc::Packet*> >*, webrtc::Operations*, webrtc::AudioDecoder*, int*, webrtc::AudioDecoder::SpeechType*) in OpenTok(neteq.neteq_impl.o)
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >* rtc::MakeCheckOpString<int, short>(int const&, short const&, char const*) in OpenTok(neteq.audio_decoder_impl.o)
"void std::__1::__sort<std::__1::__less<unsigned char, unsigned char>&, unsigned char*>(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, std::__1::__less<unsigned char, unsigned char>&)", referenced from:
webrtc::Sort(void*, unsigned int, webrtc::Type) in OpenTok(system_wrappers.sort.o)
void boost::detail::spread_sort_rec<unsigned char*, int, unsigned char>(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, std::__1::vector<unsigned char*, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char*> >&, unsigned int, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >&) in OpenTok(system_wrappers.sort.o)
"void std::__1::__sort<std::__1::__less<unsigned short, unsigned short>&, unsigned short*>(unsigned short*, unsigned short*, std::__1::__less<unsigned short, unsigned short>&)", referenced from:
webrtc::Sort(void*, unsigned int, webrtc::Type) in OpenTok(system_wrappers.sort.o)
void boost::detail::spread_sort_rec<unsigned short*, int, unsigned short>(unsigned short*, unsigned short*, std::__1::vector<unsigned short*, std::__1::allocator<unsigned short*> >&, unsigned int, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >&) in OpenTok(system_wrappers.sort.o)
"std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::append(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
rtc::HttpParseAttributes(char const*, unsigned long, std::__1::vector<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >&) in OpenTok(rtc_base.httpcommon.o)
"std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(unsigned long long)", referenced from:
webrtc::WebRtcSession::WebRtcSession(cricket::ChannelManager*, rtc::Thread*, rtc::Thread*, cricket::PortAllocator*, webrtc::MediaStreamSignaling*) in OpenTok(libjingle_peerconnection.webrtcsession.o)
cricket::Connection::ToString() const in OpenTok(rtc_p2p.port.o)
webrtc::WebRtcSessionDescriptionFactory::InternalCreateOffer(webrtc::CreateSessionDescriptionRequest) in OpenTok(libjingle_peerconnection.webrtcsessiondescriptionfactory.o)
webrtc::WebRtcSessionDescriptionFactory::InternalCreateAnswer(webrtc::CreateSessionDescriptionRequest) in OpenTok(libjingle_peerconnection.webrtcsessiondescriptionfactory.o)
```

However, the lipo command confirms that the framework does support both armv7 and arm64 architectures:

```
$> lipo -info OpenTok.framework/OpenTok
Architectures in the fat file: OpenTok.framework/OpenTok are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64
```

I'm at my wit's end, any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I got this resolved thanks to a prompt response from OpenTok support team! I'd posted the same question on their support forum as well. (https://forums.tokbox.com/post55977)

Here's the solution that worked for me (verbatim from the above link)

```
What are your Build settings? armv7 is supported.

also make sure that you have added the new lib/frameworks as follows:

- Add VideoToolbox.framework.
- Remove libstdc++ and add libc++
- add GLKit.framework (if not there previously)
```

A couple of the above mentioned files were missing from my frameworks list. I'm attaching a screenshot of the complete list, just in case someone else comes across the same issue.

I wasted close to 6 hours on this!! :(

[image]

Comment: You saved me 6 hours!